# Why doesn't the OL KMZ example work with my file?

Tags: openlayers, kml, kmz

I need to view KMZ files with OpenLayers.

The KMZ I am working with is on [GitHub](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-so/wash_kmz/blob/main/wash.kmz).

The structure of the KMZ (zip) file is:

```
wash/
    files/
        wash-dc.png
    wash-dc.kml
```

wash-dc.png is:

[image: dc]

The content of the kml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <Icon>
        <href>files/wash-dc.png</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>38.9098629826801456</north>
        <south>38.8880073821501711</south>
        <east>-77.0497762322933539</east>
        <west>-77.0120905091252439</west>
        <rotation>0</rotation>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

If I double click on the kmz file, the Google Earth App I have installed on my local machine launches and successfully displays the KMZ:

[image: google earth]

I have found the OpenLayers example on [OpenLayers website](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-kmz.html).

However, when I try dropping my KMZ file on it, it does not work. There are no errors in the console. The view in DC is:

[image: ol example]

How would this sample code need to change so my KMZ can be viewed? Or, is there something wrong with my KMZ?

Comment: I would say the KML parser in OpenLayers doesn't support GroundOverlays. See: [Does OpenLayers supports KML Ground Overlays?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/does-openlayers-supports-kml-ground-overlays), [How to display KML image overlays in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16828/how-to-display-kml-image-overlays-in-openlayers)

Comment: agreed. If you wanted to write that as the answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, the KML parser in OpenLayers doesn't support GroundOverlays.

See (old, but still relevant):

- [Does OpenLayers supports KML Ground Overlays?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/does-openlayers-supports-kml-ground-overlays)
- [How to display KML image overlays in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16828/how-to-display-kml-image-overlays-in-openlayers)

[source code for KML](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/format/KML.js)